# crontabでpython3: command not foundとなってしまう。

Tags: python, cron

crontabで`python3`コマンドが使えません。対処法を教えていただけませんでしょうか。
なお、`python3`ではなく`python`コマンドにすると動作します。

■crontab -e
`#*/1 * * * * python3 /home/vagrant/work/test.py;`

■error
`Jan  3 13:32:02 localhost CROND[28814]: (vagrant) CMD (python3         /home/vagrant/work/test.py;)`
`Jan  3 13:32:02 localhost CROND[28812]: (vagrant) CMDOUT (/bin/sh: python3: command not found)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PATHの通ってないところに`python3`があるのでしょう。cronが認識するPATHは、シェルのPATHとは違います。

`python3`をフルパスで記述するとよいです。

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/local/bin/python3 /home/vagrant/work/test.py;
```

実行ファイルがどこにあるかは、`which`で確認できます。

```
% which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

crontabに`PATH=`を記述することで追加すると言う方法もあるのですが、環境によって書き方が変わるので、フルパスで書く癖を付けた方がよいです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。フルパスで無事動作させることができました。